# Error: Could not initialize class ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseUtil

Tags: jdbc, clickhouse

I'm using `clickhouse-jdbc` in my java application. And I'm adding it to `pom.xml` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.clickhouse</groupId>
    <artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```

And when I run my java application `java -jar myapp.jar`. It's throwing:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseUtil

And in my packaged jar file, there is also `ClickHouseUtil.class`. And I'm using `Intellij Idea` for packaging jar. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 'Could not initialize class ....' means that the JVM has already tried and failed to perform static initialization of the class mentioned.

Static initialization of a class involves assigning values to any `static` fields and running any `static { ... }` blocks. The class in question is [`ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseUtil`](https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/yandex/clickhouse/ClickHouseUtil.java), and static initialization of this class consists only of setting up the static final field `CLICKHOUSE_ESCAPER`.  This appears to rely on a couple of Guava escaper classes (`com.google.common.escape.Escaper` and `com.google.common.escape.Escapers`).

So I suspect that these Guava classes aren't in your packaged JAR file.

It's also worth pointing out that the exception message 'Could not initialize class ....' means that static initialization has *already* failed.  In other words, when this exception is thrown, it is at least the second time the JVM has failed to load the class.  It's possible that your app may have reported a more informative error message when the JVM failed to load this class for the first time.